# Display Data in a List format in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table data like below :

[image]

Expected Result :

[image]

Query I am trying :

```
select Id, string_to_array(element_X::text,',')::int[] from table;
```

But its giving in a curly braces ( I understand, its just an array ). Is it possible to display it in a square bracket.

Result as of now :

[image: Current Result]

Is it possible to display like that

Comment: Displaying results happens on the client. It should be easy to replace the braces of the text representation with brackets in client code.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO) says

> The decoration consists of curly braces ({ and }) around the array
> value plus delimiter characters between adjacent items

Its indeed the representation of array. If you want just for display you can use something like `translate`.

```
with arry as(
select id, string_to_array(element_X::text,',')::int[] as element_X_arry from table
)
select id, translate(element_X_arry::text,'{}','[]') from arry
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a669c2d5f905e498aee507ffc986d6b0)